# Swapping two divs on Click in JQuery vice versa

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask how can I swap two divs vice versa without using a child selector? Since the two divs are in different parents.

```
<div class="ws_getprice_from">
   My content 1
</div>
<div class="ws_getprice_to">
   My content 2
</div>

<button class="from-to__flip">Flip</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.from-to__flip').click(function() {
        
    });
});
```

Sample: https://markuphero.com/share/U6nitwFOqeGZGOEq5Ojw

Comment: when you say swap, what do you mean? toggling them ?

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more html code or can you create an minimal runnable example?

Comment: @NicholasMberev I want to switch their position or content inside it.